# I/O relation of data when using RxJS observables

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

I want to hide a part of the data that traverses through observable operators so integrety is maintained.

For example if I have a data object like `{ private, public }` and I want to do:

1. pluck the `public` property and pass it to a custom stream `custom$`
2. after `custom$` has completed I want to restore the relation, so that I have an object `{ private, data }`, where data is the result of the `custom$` stream.

I don't want to use `concatMap`, because the `custom$` could potentially block incoming data and make the stream "slow".

I am currently using the following, but it seems very cumbersome and feels like I am doing something wrong:

```js
console.clear();

const input$ = new Rx.Subject();
const custom = data$ => data$.switchMap(
  ({ value, delay }) => Rx.Observable.of(`data ${value}`).delay(delay)
);

const out$ = input$.mergeMap(
  ({ secret, data }) =>
    Rx.Observable.zip(
      Rx.Observable.of(data).let(data$ => custom(data$)),
      Rx.Observable.of(secret)
    ));


out$.subscribe(([data, secret]) => console.log(data, '=', secret));

input$.next({ secret: 1, data: { value: 1, delay: 4000 }});
input$.next({ secret: 2, data: { value: 2, delay: 1000 }});
input$.next({ secret: 3, data: { value: 3, delay: 3000 }});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

**Is there an easier/more sane way to do this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument of all the [`*Map`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-mergeMap) operators is a result selector which takes the result of flattening a stream and allows you to rejoin it with the original argument.

```
const input$ = new Rx.Subject();
const custom = data$ => data$.switchMap(
  ({ value, delay }) => Rx.Observable.of(`data ${value}`).delay(delay)
);

const out$ = input$.mergeMap(
  ({ secret, data }) => Rx.Observable.of(data).let(custom), 
  ({secret}, newData) => ({secret, data: newData})
);


out$.subscribe(({data, secret}) => console.log(data, '=', secret));
```

Comment: Thank! I feel very dump now :-) Was staring at the documentation forever and didn't notice that there was a selector function.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do what you want :

***Your data***

```
const { Observable } = Rx;

const init$ = Observable.from([
  { secret: 1, data: { value: 1, delay: 4000 }},
  { secret: 2, data: { value: 2, delay: 1000 }},
  { secret: 3, data: { value: 3, delay: 3000 }}
]);
```

***Streams:***

```
const public$ = init$.pluck('data');

const final$ = public$.last().withLatestFrom(init$).map(x => x[0]);
```

***How to check if it does what you want:***

```
final$
  .do(console.log)
  .subscribe();
```

***Output:***

```
Object {value: 3, delay: 3000}
```

You might use `public$` safely here as there's not the secret data and then for you if you want the latest (complete) value of the initial stream you can use `final$`.

Here's a demo : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VbJEvW?editors=0010